# End-to-end working example of retrieving HTTP POST parameters in Flask?

Tags: flask

Flask version: 0.12
gunicorn version: 19.7.1
Python version: 2.7.10

Flask always throws an error when I do anything with the global request object (that's where HTTP POST data goes).

RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.

The official example at
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#a-minimal-application

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        do_the_login()
    else:
        show_the_login_form()
```

gives the same error.

I went through at least 10 other examples and none of them worked (always the same error). I also checked on how to set up or get a request context (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/reqcontext/) and the documentation there was an incoherent mess.

Other online examples I found either didn't work or were too specific to be useful.

Can someone post an example of a HTTP POST Flask app that prints the POST parameters?

Comment: Try you add  ```app = Flask(__name__)``` before of ```@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])```

Comment: @julian I already have that at the top of my test script. Does it need to be right before the @app.route?

Comment: then, check out this doc it speaks about contexts [context app](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/appcontext/)

Comment: How are you running this script and what OS are you running it in?

Comment: Mac OS. Running the server as gunicorn -b localhost:<port> <script>:<app>. HTTP POST is done from the browser. Finally, can someone post a working end-to-end example already? Complete script would be preferable. I checked out the document that Julian posted on context app and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The problem is that gunicorn fails at handling HTTP POST. Works after exporting the FLASK_APP environment variable and running.

On the command line:

```
export FLASK_APP=path/to/my/flask/script.py
flask run -p [port number]
```

In the flask script:

```
@app.route("/example_app", methods=["POST"])
example_function(request.form["field"])
return "finished"
```